# Getting table row value in checkbox and sending mail consisting the particular values

Tags: codeigniter, twig

I'm struggling in getting the table row values inside a checkbox and also i want to send email to users consisting of the same checkbox values selected.

```
{% block main_content %}

{% set msgclasses = {'success': 'shj_g', 'notice': 'shj_o', 'error':'shj_r'} %}
{% for message in messages %}
    <p class="{{ msgclasses[message.type] }}">{{ message.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% if all_assignments|length == 0 %}
    <p style="text-align: center;">Nothing to show...</p>
{% else %}
    <br/>
    <table id="mytable" class="sharif_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select Assessments</th>
                <th>Assessment Statistics</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Problem Statement</th>
                <th>Submissions</th>
                <th>Coefficient</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Finish Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                {% if user.level > 0 %}

                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for item in all_assignments|reverse %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="item.name"/></td>
                <td><i class="pointer select_assignment fa {{ item.id == user.selected_assignment.id ? 'fa-check-square-o color6' : 'fa-square-o' }} fa-2x" data-id="{{ item.id }}"></i></td>
                <td dir="auto">{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ site_url('assignments/pdf/'~item.id) }}"><img src="{{ base_url('assets/images/pdf.svg') }}" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ item.total_submits }} submission{{ item.total_submits != 1 ? 's' }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if item.finished %}
                        <span style="color: red;">Finished</span>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ item.coefficient }} %
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>{{ item.start_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.finish_time }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if item.open %}
                        <span style="color: green;">Open</span>
                    {% else %}
                        <span style="color: red;">Close</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </td>

                {% if user.level > 0 %}
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

checkbox should take the values of certain table rows and the values have to be passed inside email body.

[image for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcJUa.jpg)

Comment: instead of putting image of a code, put code that'll be more convenient

Comment: Paste the code as text

Comment: The checkboxes don't even have a name so nothing will be posted, also ou shouldn't be using a non-unique value for checkboxes. You are better off using the id of the student as value